# node.js server not receive all binary data (or client not sending all binary data)

Tags: node.js, binary, express, request

I'm very new to node.js and am running into a problem that is probably very basic, I'm sure I'm just not "getting" something, but here we go:

I've got two programs...

- server.js is a simple express/node.js server that accepts a POST of binary data
- client.js is a simple request/node.js client that streams the contents of a large file to the server

I've been scouring stackoverflow for suggestions and I think I've a small example of the issue:

Client:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
fs.createReadStream('test2.zip').pipe(request.post('http://localhost:3000/'));
```

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var size = 0;

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        size += data.length;
        console.log('Got chunk: ' + data.length + ' total: ' + size);
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("total size = " + size);
    }); 

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR ERROR: " + e.message);
    });

    res.send("Thanks");
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

When I send a small file or if I POST data from an external client like Advanced REST Client in Chrome I see what I would expect:

```
Got chunk: 481 total: 481
total size = 481
```

But if I send a large file I see a bunch of data come through and then it stops:

```
Got chunk: 65405 total: 65405
Got chunk: 131 total: 65536
Got chunk: 65396 total: 130932
Got chunk: 140 total: 131072
Got chunk: 65387 total: 196459
Got chunk: 149 total: 196608
Got chunk: 65378 total: 261986
Got chunk: 158 total: 262144
Got chunk: 65369 total: 327513
Got chunk: 167 total: 327680
Got chunk: 65360 total: 393040
Got chunk: 176 total: 393216
Got chunk: 65351 total: 458567
Got chunk: 185 total: 458752
Got chunk: 65342 total: 524094
Got chunk: 194 total: 524288
Got chunk: 65333 total: 589621
Got chunk: 203 total: 589824
Got chunk: 65324 total: 655148
Got chunk: 212 total: 655360
Got chunk: 15898 total: 671258
```

It looks like the data stops without 'end' getting called. It's also interesting that the data is coming in large/small chunks.

Any ideas? Is express choking on the binary data?

node.js v0.10.7, express v3.2.4, request v2.21.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: You have 2 mistakes.

1. Never calling `res.end`
2. Calling `res.send` before getting the `end` event.

Here's the modified `server.js` snippet with the `res.end` line being the interesting move/change.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var size = 0;

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        size += data.length;
        console.log('Got chunk: ' + data.length + ' total: ' + size);
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("total size = " + size);
        res.end("Thanks");
    }); 

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR ERROR: " + e.message);
    });

});
```

With that fix, all works as expected with both small and large test files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Interesting thought on the keep-alive. Since the client terminates immediately I would think the the socket would close, but I get that the server might not see that. I can ty to disable keep alive and see if that changes anything.

Something is still not right though. The file is 243967953 bytes but I only see a small subset of that come through.

Also, with a small file I get the 'end' call using the same code... could something to do with the size of the file.

Comment: Well, it's a 1-chunk vs N-chunks distinction I think. When I run client.js to a mock server of just `nc -l 3000` the client hangs with the TCP connection open.

Comment: Sure it is, it's waiting for the HTTP response from the server, right?

Comment: Specifically, it's waiting for a complete response, which a single `res.send` won't accomplish. But there's also a timing issue in that your code is sending response data before reading all of the request body, and that may be fine, but I'd have to research that a bit to understand if there are edge cases there.

Comment: That's it! Makes total sense. Thanks so much for the help. I knew it had to be something basic... I'm not thinking asynchronously yet.